# switch case in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have this code that returns in the line *result.locationList[x].location* values, which I would like to manipulate:

```
                    for (x=0; x<result.locationList.length; x++) {
                        locationListHTML += '<div class="groupLocation">';
                        if (result.locationList[x].availability) {
                            locationListHTML += '<span class="availableLoc">
                                + result.locationList[x].location + '</span> ';
                        } else {
                            locationListHTML += '<span class="checkedoutLoc">'  
                                + result.locationList[x].location + '</span> ';
                        }
```

To achieve this I created a switch, but it doesn't work:

```
                    for (x=0; x<result.locationList.length; x++) {
                        locationListHTML += '<div class="groupLocation">';
                        if (result.locationList[x].availability) {
                        switch (result.locationList[x].availability)
                              {
                              case "123-ABC: Hamburg":
                                location="Hamburg";
                                break;
                              case "123-ABC: Berlin":
                                location="Berlin";
                                break;
                              case "123-ABC: Munich":
                                location="Munich";
                                break;
                              case "123-ABC: Dusseldorf":
                                location="Dusseldorf";
                                break;
                              case "123-ABC: Dresden":
                                location="Dresden";
                                break;
                              } 
                            locationListHTML += '<span class="availableLoc">
                                + result.locationList[x].location + '</span> ';
                        } else {
                            locationListHTML += '<span class="checkedoutLoc">'  
                                + result.locationList[x].location + '</span> ';
                        }
```

As I am not very familiar with Javascript, I'd be thankful for a hint where to start debugging?

Christian

Comment: Using the Developer's console , you can debug. Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome .

Comment: Why use a switch when you could simply use `result.locationList[x].availability.split(':')[1].trim()` ?

Comment: What do you mean that "it doesn't work"? What is unexpected result? Is there some error output?

Comment: It looks like you are assigning the result of the case to the variable location, but from what I can tell it only exists within the case statement. You will have to declare the variable outside of the case statement to be able to use it later on.

Comment: You should add a default statement in your switch and yes use the debug tools to track the value of `result.locationList[x].availability` maybe you have an issue with upper/lower case

Comment: @dystroy: Thanks! That's much mor simple :) and it worked perfect for me

Comment: @ChristianDabrowski I made it an answer, so that it's cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a complex switch, it's better to simply get the information that is already present in your string.

That is you should use

```
location = result.locationList[x].availability.split(':').pop().trim();
```

The reasons it's better is that you won't have to maintain a list if the number of possible cases grows, and you won't risk to have a error in this list. By the way a shorter code is easier to manage (when it's readable).

Notes :

- If you expect that your strings might not follow the model you give, you'll have to handle errors according to your application. For example you might want to issue an error message if `result.locationList[x].availability.split(':')` hasn't a length of 2.
- I assumed the `location` variable was already declared, that's why I didn't put `var`. If it isn't, add it : you can have many bugs coming from not explicitly declared variables.

While error handling *has* to be dependent on the strings you expect and how you want to react, here's how you could organize them (here using a regex but that's the same) :

```
var m = result.locationList[x].availability.match(/[^\:]*:\s?(.*)/);
if (m.length==2) {
     var location = m[1];
     // use location
} else {
     // the input string isn't good, maybe it's empty or
     //  it doesn't contain the : char. Alert the user or the police
     //  or use a default value instead
}
```

Comment: What if `location` is empty. Can I add there an `!empty` like in PHP  to make it only work when a value is delivered?

Comment: You can do `result.locationList[x].availability.split(':')[1].trim() || defaultValue` but what exactly do you expect to be empty ?

Comment: I have here cases where there is simply no value. In my case it causes the rotating gif-picture which is shown while the availabilty status is being checked, never stops to turn when there there is no value to trim.

Answer (score 1):

Java Scripts code in Visual Studio is a simple way to debugging it.you must write code on a Js File and add it to Project .for example write your code on js file such as "blub.js" .you must reference it from the page that it used. or drag and drop the file to page for easy way.you can use select the result.locationList[x].location code.you use QuickWatch Tool for to see the current value.